# Can't figure out what path to use in background-image: url(); to get a certain image in a Vue.js project

Tags: css

Currently I have a Vue.js project with this file tree (showing only relevant folders and files):

```
root
    src
        assets
            image.jpg
        components
            header.vue
    index.html
```

So inside the header.vue component, I have this CSS code:

```
.background-image {
    background-image: url();
}
```

and I need to reference the image.jpg file inside the assets folder. I tried so many different combinations and never saw the image, so I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
.background-image {
    background-image: url('../assets/image.jpg');
}
```

If it's not showing, one possible reason is that, the element `.background-image` doesn't have a height especially if it doesn't have any content yet. Try adding `padding` or `height`.

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url("../assets/image.jpg");
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Ah dang, so I did get the path right but since it didn't have height, it wasn't displaying. So this is the answer. Thanks.